# ListDictionary data retrieving cannot be possible

Tags: c#, list

I am using a `ListDictionary`

```
ListDictionary lstTime = new ListDictionary();
```

which includes two types of data (`int` and `time`).

```
lstTime.Add(1, datetime.time));
```

Through this method I can add data to the `ListDictionary`.

But how can I retrieve the data from the `ListDictionary`?

Comment: Can you post a complete example?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Maybe you should show how you're trying to retrieve values.

Comment: If you would just **look at the official documentation** for [ListDictionary on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there would be **at least 3 ways** of how to access and read out the values from the `ListDictionary` ....

Comment: We cannot help if you're not collaborative :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but I'm becoming more and more reluctant to helping users with reputation 1 and automatically assigned names.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ListDictionary lstTime = new ListDictionary();
lstTime.Add(1,DateTime.Today);
foreach ( DictionaryEntry de in lstTime )
  Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", de.Key, de.Value );
```

I get:

```
1: 28/10/2014 00.00.00
```

Single values can be retrivied like this

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)lstTime[1];
```

Note: I changed `datetime.time` to `DateTime.Today` as I have no idea what `datetime.time` is.